# Fabricjs: entering IText with click on canvas

Tags: fabricjs

The objective of [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/hsLwjtbx/4/) is the following:

- User clicks on canvas
- A cursor shows up where the user clicked
- User can enter text

I tried to use IText `enterEditing` method right after the user clicks on the canvas, but the cursor does not show up, so the user don't know they can enter text. In addition, in Chrome and Firefox the user cannot enter text at all. Any ideas?

Javascript

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {
    if (options.target == null) 
         addText(options.e);
});


function addText(e) {

        var text = new fabric.IText('',{
            left: e.offsetX,
            top: e.offsetY
        });

        canvas.add(text);
        text.enterEditing();
}
```

Comment: I faced with same issue. did you find solution?

Answer (score 6):

Try the following code, you need to set your text object as active object in canvas.

```
var text = new fabric.IText('',{
  left: e.offsetX,
  top: e.offsetY
});
canvas.add(text).setActiveObject(text);
text.enterEditing();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle i upaded using this code,Hope it can help you somewhat

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {

    if (options.target == null) 
        addText(options.e);
});


function addText(e) {

  var custontxt=new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', { 
  fontFamily: 'helvetica',
  fontSize:30,
  fontWeight:400,
  fill:'red', 
  fontStyle: 'normal', 
  top:250,
  cursorDuration:500,    
  left:250,    
});  
canvas.add(custontxt);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hsLwjtbx/16/

Comment: Any idea how to detect if any object is active or not on `canvas.on('mouse:down'` basically, addText only should be called if no other object is active.

Comment: You can use `canvas.getActiveObject()` to check whether or not an object is active